# Content Provider Protection Level using Signature

Tags: android

To protect malicious applications from accessing a content provider, 1 way is to set the  android:protectionLevel="signature".

This way, only another app that has been signed with the same signature could access the contents of a content provider.

But is it safe? How does it check the signature? For example I have a signed App A, is the signature stored somewhere for another app to check?

Or the checking is done by another mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

According to Android Developer Guide.

> A permission that the system grants only if the requesting application is signed with the same certificate as the application that declared the permission. If the certificates match, the system automatically grants the permission without notifying the user or asking for the user's explicit approval.

To forge a signature you need know a private key that was used to sign an application. So it's pretty safe for now (especially if you believe that P != NP :) ).